# Проблемы с ООП в PHP

Tags: php, ооп, классы

У меня имеется 3 класса, engine, template, user. Я подключаю в engine остальные 2 класса.

```
include_once 'model/template.php';
include_once 'model/user.php';

class Engine {
    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->tpl = new Template();
        $this->user = new User();
    }
}
```

И как будет правильнее использовать класс Template в User классе? И вообще возможно такое или нет? Или надо в User заново подключать Template?

**Обновление**

Я нашел только такой выход:

```
$this->user = new User($this->tpl);
```

Просто передать в класс переменную, и потом в User классе использовать ее как местную

```
class User {
    function __construct($tpl) {
        $this->tpl = $tpl;
    }
}
```

Не знаю на сколько это правильно, может будут решения получше.

Comment: Если делать `new User($this->tpl)` то ничего подключать не придется.. Только вот юзер наверное ничего не должен знать ни про какие шаблоны